Set border in Apache eChart around chart
Is there a way to create a border around in Apache eChart?
I've looked in the docs, tried various combinations, but can't seem to put a border around a chart.
I have them in a table and can add borders that way, but being able to add tehm to teh chart and not the table would be nice.

You can put a border around the grid in echarts. Using a second grid which contains the main grid you can create a border around the chart.
Example:
option = {
  grid: [
    {},
    {
      left: 0,
      top: 0,
      right: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      show: true,
      borderColor: 'red',
      borderWidth: 1
    }
  ],
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [120, 200, 150, 80, 70, 110, 130],
      type: 'bar'
    }
  ]
};

You could also put a border on the div element used by echarts.
